# GCP Pub/Sub Publisher process hangs forever while using Java API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I was successfully able to publish message into Pub/Sub topic till yesterday. But from today morning code is getting hanged forever during publishing. My problem is same as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295892/com-google-cloud-pubsub-spi-v1-publisher-publish-is-not-sending-data-to-pubsub). 
Then I have tried to create a topic using Java API as describe in the code snippet below

```
TopicName topic = TopicName.create(projectId, topicId);

try {
  TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create();
  topicAdminClient.createTopic(topic); //HANG FOREVER
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code is hanging again at `topicAdminClient.createTopic`.

I am using `com.google.pubsub.v1` package for GCP Pub/Sub along with `com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient`. I have tried with default authentication credential as well as setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL` with *Service Account Key*. I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

My code to publish message is as below

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("JSON file path"));
ApiFuture<String> messageId = publishMessage(publisher, 
ByteString.copyFrom(IOUtils.toByteArray(fis)));
```

where publishMessage is defined as below

```
private static ApiFuture<String> publishMessage(Publisher publisher, ByteString message)
            throws Exception {
    // convert message to bytes
    PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = 
    PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(message).build();
    return publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
}
```

Additional Info: 
I have tried to execute datastore Java api and it is executing seamlessly. Maybe the problem is only with Pubsub I guess.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue, but I'm running from a main method in IntelliJ, so the accepted answer doesn't help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The problem is resolved. Mistakenly I forgot to mention packaging type in pom file. Once I mention the packaging type as jar (jar) it's started working.